# Session Preview doen't work if publication path and URL is different

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, session-preview

I faced a XPM Session Preview problem.

That is, if "Publication Path" and "Publication URL" of publication property has different value, Session Preview doen't work.

**Publication properties**

Publication Path: \jp_ja

Publication URL: /jp/ja

**Problem**

Modification by In Line Edit disappears, and "Update the page preview" message appears again and again. This is a typical symptom of a Session Preview error.

If I only modify publication property and input same value on "Publication Path" and "Publication URL", then Session Preview works fine.

My questions are following:

1. How can I make Session Preview work when "Publication Path" and "Publication URL" is different.
2. Is there any description on Tridion manual about this issue, i.e. if "Publication Path" and "Publication URL" is different, Session Preview doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to configure the path to your site in the cd_dynamic_conf.xml file of your website.

```
  <Publication Id="99">
    <Host Domain="your-website.com" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/jp/ja" />
  </Publication>
```

There is an excellent question on this by [Dominic](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/129/dominic-cronin) here:
[What contribution does cd_dynamic_conf make to the workings of Experience Manager?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/what-contribution-does-cd-dynamic-conf-make-to-the-workings-of-experience-manage)

(Dominic also comments on the documentation issue too.)

Comment: My configration is same as you suggests. cd_dynamic_conf is <Publication Id="364">
 <Host Domain="dev01" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/jp/ja"/></Publication>. And web site URL is "http://dev01/jp/ja/". But still it doen't work. It's Storange.

Comment: Have you also configured this on your [Session Preview web service](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-89DF43CD-9B5A-4858-B830-B3D2BCAAB1BF) (login required)

Comment: Yes, Session Preview web service(cd_preview_webservice)'s cd_dynamic_conf has same setting. XPM requests URL based on Publication Path, for example "http://dev01/jp_ja/pageA.html". I wish that XPM requests URL like "http://dev01/jp/ja/pageA.html".

Comment: Have you added the URL of your Staging website to the 'Session Preview' tab of the Staging Publication Target?  This is described in step 6 of the [Setting up publishing for Experience Manager](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-6A8C7A13-A652-4134-B93E-9AFED1A7DC22) (login required).  Can you confirm whether the Session Preview web service is being called (from the IIS logs or the Tridion logs) and whether the Session Preview database is being populated?

Comment: Yes, Publication Target's Session Preview tab Website URLs contains "http://dev01/jp/ja". Also Content "Delivery Endpoint URL" is correct. In Session Preview web service DB, HTML source code modified on XPM is generated, this means Session Preview web service was called. And in the staging web site's log file, following log is output:"PathOptionMatcher - The Path DOES NOT match. Mapped path is [jp/ja] and extracted path is [jp_ja/products/test/index.jsp]." It seems XPM is using Publication Path, not Publication URL.

Comment: It sounds like you have configured Experience Manager correctly.  I suspect that this may be a bug in the product.  One for Tridion Support I think.  However, it may also be worth adding the error message that you're getting to the question incase anyone else here has seen this before on 2013.